# TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable

Tags: python, iteration

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/RCS/Desktop/Project/SHM.py", line 435, in <module>
    app = SHM()
  File "C:/Users/RCS/Desktop/Project/SHM.py", line 34, in __init__
    frame = F(container, self)
  File "C:/Users/RCS/Desktop/Project/SHM.py", line 384, in __init__
    if "3202" in q:
TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable
```

code

**some part of code, initialisation and all**

```
while 1:
    q = variable1.get
    if "3202" in q:
        variable2.set("NI NODE3202")
        try:
            switch(labelframe2, labelframe1)
        except:
            switch(labelframe3, labelframe1)
    elif "3212" in q:
        variable2.set("NI NODE3212")
        try:
            switch(labelframe1, labelframe2)
        except:
            switch(labelframe3, labelframe2)
    elif "3214" in q:
        variable2.set("NI NODE3214")
        try:
            switch(labelframe1, labelframe3)
        except:
            switch(labelframe2, labelframe3)
    else:
        None
```

**some other part of code**

```
def switch(x, y):

    if x.isGridded:
        x.isGridded = False
        x.grid_forget()
        y.isGridded = True
        y.grid(row=0, column=0)
    else: 
        return False
```

I am trying to create a switch between three `labelframe`s which are inside another `labelframe`, and outside this `labelframe` are other `labelframe`s that are not changing.

I have read some similar answers but I don't want to use `__iter__()` in my code. Can anybody provide any other suggestions?

Comment: I am guessing you want to do - `q = variable1.get()` ?

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to *call* the `Entry.get()` method:

```
q = variable1.get()
#                ^^ call the method
```

Because the method object itself doesn't support containment testing directly, Python is instead trying to iterate over the object to see if there are any elements contained in it that match your string.

If you *call* the method, you get a string value instead. Strings do support containment testing.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you got that error was because you did not add "()" after.get query hence the error to fix this change `q = variable1.get` to `q = variable.get()`